# Converting file to BinaryTree

Tags: java, binary-tree, bufferedreader

I'm currently in the process of writing a question game in Java using Binary Trees. I have written all of the methods necessary but I changed something in my code and the program now seems to delete the contents of the file to be read before it actually executes readLine() resulting in a NullPointerException. I'm actually stumped as to what is happening and any explanation would be much appreciated!

The file itself is in the correct directory with contents (all Strings):

Horse
null
null (each is on a separate line starting at the top)

After the program crashes, the file is empty.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at animalgame.BinaryTree.loadTree(BinaryTree.java:63)
at animalgame.AnimalGame.<init>(AnimalGame.java:26)
at animalgame.AnimalGameTester.main(AnimalGameTester.java:21)
```

Java Result: 1

This is a call to my constructor:

```
AnimalGame game = new AnimalGame();
```

This is the constructor:

```
public AnimalGame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\andre_000\\Desktop\\knowledge.txt"));
    this.out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\andre_000\\Desktop\\knowledge.txt"));
    this.gameTree = BinaryTree.loadTree(this.in);
}
```

And this is an excerpt for the loadTree method:

```
public static BinaryTree loadTree(BufferedReader in) throws IOException 
{
    String value = in.readLine();

    if (value.equals("null")) 
    {
        return NIL;
    }
```

There is more to the loadTree method that specifies what happens when value doesn't equal "null", but the program crashes on the first comparison even though the first line is "Horse"

Thank you!

EDIT 1:

A call to System.out.println(value) after String value = in.readLine() prints out null even though the first line in the file is "Horse"!

EDIT 2:

Still no dice. Tried closing the streams as per my friend's suggestion. Has no effect.

Comment: Which is the 63rd line of the BinaryTree class?

Comment: Its the line if (value.equals("null")). Sorry about the lack of numbering.

Answer (score 0):

probably this line may be causing the issue,

```
if (value.equals("null"))
```

you can check null as below

```
if (value != null)
```

Comment: The file actually contains Strings "null" to mark the endpoints of the Binary Tree. The checks worked fine at one point of the program but with the above setup, im crashing for some reason